# Convert mangled characters back to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, windows-1252, codepage-437

Here is what I did:

1. I dumped a SQLite database with UTF-8 data (`sqlite3 example.db .dump > dump.sql`), but since this was in powershell, I assume the piping converted it to windows-1252
2. I loaded that dumped data into a new database, again using powershell (`Get-Content dump.sql | sqlite3 example2.db`)
3. I dumped that *new* database and am left with a new `.sql` file (this time it was *not* through powershell - so I assume it was unmodified)

This new sql file's UTF-8 characters are seriously mangled, and I was wondering if there was a way to convert it back into correct UTF-8.

As a few examples, here are what some sequences are in the *new* file, and what they *should* be (all are viewed as UTF-8):

1. `ÒüéÒü¬ÒüƒÒü½` *should be* `あなたに`
2. `´╝ü` *should be* a full width exclamation mark
3. `Òé¡Òé╗Òé¡` *should be* `キセキ`

Does anyone have any idea as to how I might undo this mangling? Any method would be very helpful!

This is in powershell 7.0.1

**Edit:**

On further inspection, you can duplicate my predicament by redirecting any such data to a file in powershell (note that the data cannot itself be entered in powershell). Hence, setting up a script like this gives the same outcome:

test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "キ"
```

And then running `wsl ./test.sh > test.txt` will give an output of `Òé¡`, not `キ`

**Edit 2:**

It seems as if the codepage the UTF-8 text was converted to is *almost* 437: some characters are restored using this assumption (e.g. `木`), but others are not. If it's close to 437, but isn't, what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, since I am in the UK, the codepage I wanted was 850. Saving the file as 850 and then reloading it as UTF-8 fixed my issue!